# mkinitcpio : command not found

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mkinitcpio

I am a **beginner** in Linux when i install arch Linux **dual boot** , download **base system** then i go to **chroot** then make a ram using a command: `mkinitcpio -p Linux`. when i write it, gives me **command not found.**
i install using this *video*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=METZCp_JCec
i stop at min: **9.16.**

Comment: Inside the `chroot` environment, please execute the `ls -l` command and post the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [2019-10-06](https://www.archlinux.org/news/base-group-replaced-by-mandatory-base-package-manual-intervention-required) it's required to install a kernel besides installing the base package.

So you have to install either linux or linux-lts (or another kernel of your choice) that will pull the mkinitcpio package as a dependency.

The [up-to-date instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Install_essential_packages) mention that you have to do : `pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware`

So in your case basically you have to do `pacstrap /mnt linux linux-firmware` outside of the chroot, and then you will get the mkinitcpio tool available once you enter the chroot.

The video you mention is from 2014, so don't take that modification into account. At [6:29](https://youtu.be/METZCp_JCec?t=389) you can see that the package linux is being pulled when he is installing base, but it's not the case anymore (you can check in the in /mnt/var/log/pacman.log file, that no linux package has been installed).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps inside the chroot environment the command is not in your path.

Please try, inside the chroot:

```
/sbin/mkinitcpio -p Linux
```

and, if that does not work,

```
/usr/sbin/mkinitcpio -p Linux
```

and let us know if it does not work.

Comment: It doesnt work , it gives me no such file or directory